Did Aristotle ever actually mention tobacco?
I found this amusing passage in Don Juan by Molière. It's a line by Sganarelle (Act 1, scene 1):

« Quoi que puisse dire Aristote et toute la philosophie, il n’est rien
d’égal au tabac : c’est la passion des honnêtes gens, et qui vit sans
tabac n’est pas digne de vivre. Non seulement il réjouit et purge les
cerveaux humains, mais encore il instruit les âmes à la vertu, et l’on
apprend avec lui à devenir honnête homme. Ne voyez-vous pas bien, dès
qu’on en prend, de quelle manière obligeante on en use avec tout le
monde, et comme on est ravi d’en donner à droite et à gauche, partout
où l’on se trouve ? On n’attend pas même qu’on en demande, et l’on
court au-devant du souhait des gens : tant il est vrai que le tabac
inspire des sentiments d’honneur et de vertu à tous ceux qui en
prennent. Mais c’est assez de cette matière.»
"No matter what Aristotle says with all his Philosophy, there’s nothing
like tobacco: it is the passion of respectable men; and the man who
lives without tobacco is not worthy to live. Not only does it
replenish and relax the human brain, but it also instructs souls in
virtue, for through it one learns how to become a sociable man.
Haven’t you ever noticed how obliging someone becomes as soon as he
has some tobacco? And how happy he is to hand it out left and right,
wherever he might be? Without even waiting to be asked, he anticipates
the wishes of others: thus it is true that tobacco inspires sentiments
of honor and virtue in those who use it. But enough of this." (translated by Brett B. Bodemer)

It got me wondering — does anyone know if Aristotle ever actually mentioned tobacco, or is this allusion just for comedic effect?

As a side note, there seem to be a mistranslation in the english version. It's not "with all his Philosophy" but "and all of philosophy". So the sentence could be understood as "No matter what Aristotle and all the others philosophers say"

Aristotle did not mention tobacco: the plant is native to the Americas, and was not known in Europe until the 16th century.
But one subject that Aristotle did write about was how to “instruct souls in virtue”, in the Nicomachean Ethics, which was in Molière’s time (and to a certain extent still is) the foundation of the philosophy of ethics in Europe.
So Sganarelle’s line means, “there’s no need to read Aristotle’s Ethics:† to become virtuous you can take up smoking instead”. Of course, this is a joke, since even if tobacco had the claimed effects, there is more to virtue than being “sociable” and “handing out tobacco left and right”.
† A note on an issue that was raised in comments. It is doubtful that Sganarelle can be supposed to have known Aristotle’s Ethics: a more plausible reading is that he was vaguely aware that Aristotle was supposed to be an authority on virtue, in the way that people today might be vaguely aware that Einstein is an authority on physics, without knowing any of his works. But Molière surely knew the Ethics (it’s one of the philosophical works briefly satirized in Le bourgeois gentilhomme), so he delivers the joke to us over the head of Sganarelle, as it were.

Hi, nitpicking here, but Sganarelle in this play is a rather unsophisticated character (see his disjointed “reasoning” about why Don Juan will end up in Hell). It is dubious he knows anything about Aristotle beyond the fact that it was the best-known philosophical authority at the time, let alone any of his books.

@Aphelli He could know that Aristotle was an authority on virtue, without knowing or reading any of his books. Just as people today know that Einstein is an authority on physics, without having to know or read any of his books.

You are right. My precise objection is that the line “There’s no need to read Aristotle’s Ethics to be virtuous…” could not plausibly emanate from Sganarelle’s mind, because it is too precise and cultured for the character. What I think is still worth mentioning is that, in this scene, another good part of the comic effect comes from the fact that Sganarelle is trying to pretend to be a savant – which does not work for the reasons that you give, as well as the contrast between the blatant triviality of tobacco and “virtue” as a philosophical concept.

It's for comic effect. Tobacco was unknown  in Europe before the 'discovery' of the Americas.
Sganarelle is probably referring to Aristotle as a philosopher who wrote on many topics and was still widely respected in the 17th century.

Late addition to this discussion, but I do want to clarify: the quote above does not suggest that Aristotle said anything about tobacco.
To be a bit more pedantic about the first line translation:

Quoi que puisse dire Aristote et toute la philosophie, il n’est rien d’égal au tabac

As has been mentioned above, "toute la philosophie" should be read as "all of philosophy," not "all of his philosophy."
"puisse" is the verb "pouvoir"/"to be able to," in the subjunctive mood: that's used to discuss a hypothetical or counterfactual situation. In French, subjonctif is particularly used when the actual state of things is outside the knowledge of the speaker (and possibly irrelevant, like when expressing hopes or fears). So "que puisse dire" is probably something more like "would say" or "might say," and the quote above is

Whatever Aristotle, and all of philosophy, might say, there's nothing that's a match for tobacco...

Translated this way, it's clear that the speaker (Sganarelle) is not making claims about what Aristotle actually said--that doesn't matter; he thinks he's right even though he expects all the "experts" would disagree.
